# Stability of Linear Systems

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, dynamical-systems

for the following matrices A, classify the stability of the linear systems x=Ax as asymptotically stable, L-stable (but not asymptotically stable) or unstable and indicate whether it is a stable node, stable degenerate node, etc:

I don't really know how to get started...can someone explain what the first step would be?

So someone said that I should look at the eigenvalues and:

a. 
 \begin{array}{cc}
   -6 & -3 \\
   2 & -1 \\
  \end{array}

$λ_1=-3$, $λ_2=-4$

Asymptotically stable

Node

b.
\begin{array}{cc}
   5 & -5 \\
   2 & -1 \\
  \end{array}

$λ_1=2+i$, $λ_2=2-i$

Unstable

Spiral Point

c.
\begin{array}{cc}
   1 & 5 \\
   -2 & -1 \\
  \end{array}

$λ_1=3i$, $λ_2=-3i$

L-stable

Center

d.
\begin{array}{cc}
   1 & -2 \\
   8 & -7 \\
  \end{array}

$λ_1=-3$, $λ_2=-3$

Asymptotically Stable

Proper Node

Comment: Do you understand what the real parts of the eigenvalues tell you?

Comment: @graydad you mean what they tell me in terms of stability? Actually not really...but the answer submitted below helped me a bit, is there anything I am missing?

Comment: @MathMajor understanding what the real parts of the eigenvalues tell you in terms of stability is critical with these types of problems. The answer below helps, as does the link above I imagine. The main thing is to remember what the sign of a derivative (or differential equation) tells you. Positive derivative values mean the function is "increasing" (not moving toward stability) while negative derivative values mean the function is "decreasing" (moving toward stability)

Comment: @Amzoti I especially like that first link! Very clear..I updated my answer, but I am not sure if it's correct..

Comment: @graydad Oh thanks! That explanation helps a lot!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For continuous linear time-invariant systems like this, you can determine stability by looking at the eigenvalues of the matrix $A$.

If the real part of each eigenvalue is strictly negative, the system is asymptotically stable. If some eigenvalues have negative real part but one or more of them has zero real part, the system is marginally stable but not asymptotically stable. If any eigenvalue has positive real part, the system is unstable.

Can you take it from here?

Comment: I edited my answer! How does it look now? Thank you for your help by the way!

Comment: Also is L stable the same as marginally stable? If not, what is L stable?

Comment: I think L stable here refers to Lyapunov stable, which is equivalent to marginally stable (as I've used the term).

Comment: I get different values for the eigenvalues for (b) and (d). For (c), should $\lambda_2$ be $3i$, not $3i6$?

Comment: Yes it does refer to lyapunov, but I like your term marginally stable better

Comment: right! for calculating b i forgot a minus sign and for c that's a typo, let me check d

Comment: hmmm i double checked d with an eigen value calculator, are you sure its not correct?

Comment: Yes, I agree with what you have for (d). I'm not sure why I wrote that before.

Comment: Ok! Thank you for all your help~

Comment: Not a problem! If you found my answer helpful, you might consider accepting it.

Comment: I was just rereading your answer and I noticed that you had said If some eigenvalues have negative real part but one or more of them has zero real part, the system is marginally stable but not asymptotically stable.", but in the case of c both eigen values have 0 real part (so no eigenvalues have a negative real part), however is it still considered marginally stable?