# Positive and negative eigenvalues - Saddle points

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, stability-theory

This is similar to another question on my page but this one is more conceptual: If you have a saddle point, is this always classified as unstable if you're doing a stability analysis? What do they mean?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1010702/692097